# Can you replace selected files in an Azure Website without deploying the whole Website?

Tags: azure, deployment, web, azure-web-app-service

When I check in my modifications to Visual Studio Online, an automatic deployment of the Azure website is done.

Is there a way to just replace some files in the Azure website, without deploying the whole website?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason this makes a difference to you?

Comment: Yes. In my Visual Studio Online subscription I have a limited build time, and each time I make a check in it builds in VS online and then deploys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can login to the site via FTP. Or you can use ServerExplorer in VisualStudio 2013 and modify files there:
[image]

Comment: I don't have the structure that you have in Server Explorer, I only see the sites names but not the files folder.

Comment: Do you have Update 2 installed in VS2013? Try FTP instead. You can get ftp details from the portal.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Kudu Debug Console to change files in your site.  Go to http:// [yoursite].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole and log in with your FTP credentials

Answer (score 1):

If you have publishing profile for azure loaded in your website then It is possible to select just your aspx pages(for design changes) .Right click aspx page and publish.

In case of code changes,full project must be published as code goes into dll's.

Comment: It's painful I know (our uploads take ~45 minutes due to our slow connection), but this is the right answer.  If you modify files on a local instance, it won't be replicated to others without it being published properly. Or if the instance becomes unrecoverable, you'll lose the changes you made.