# Azure, working connection-string but says has not been initialized

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

Playing with azure, have a connection string. When the web app hits the first call that requires hitting the database i get this exception.

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

the stack trace is

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1.IsIdentityV1Schema(DbContext db)
```

Fortunatley its on my constructor:

```
public SisyphusContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
```

and the connection string in there is valid. I took it, made a console app opened a connection selected a load of data. Interestingly the web app when it started successfully seeded the database presumably using this very connection string. (Well we know it cant of ...)

So my question: What is going on? How do i fix it?
Everything i have found suggests the string is wrong, but i have shown this is not the case. I suspect its magicking a connection string from somewhere but i cannto find it (in configs or publish files)

Although that said the seeding uses UserManager and RoleManager, wheras this uses my DbContext. That said i pass my context using the constructor here to build it - so thats probably not useful.

update:

here are the connection strings as part of deployment: found in `obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp` of the web project.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
         connectionString="$(ReplacableToken_DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String_0)"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Sisyphus.Core.Repository.SisyphusContext" connectionString="$(ReplacableToken_Sisyphus.Core.Repository.SisyphusContext-Web.config Connection String_0)"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="Sisyphus.Core.Repository.SisyphusContext_DatabasePublish"
         connectionString="$(ReplacableToken_Sisyphus.Core.Repository.SisyphusContext_DatabasePublish-Web.config Connection String_0)" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

The thing is the connection string works. Just not in azure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that Azure Web-Site or Web-Service?

In case of **Web-Sites**, Azure has connection strings in it's own configuration (Configuration page within portal). Check there if connection string is set.

[image: Azure portal configuration page with Connection Strings]

You have 2 options here: keep connection string set in Azure config: make sure it is a correct one. Or delete connection strings from Azure entirely and use `web.config` settings. And if you are using `web.config`, make sure you transform your connection string correctly when deploying.

If your connection strings are fine in Azure portal, I'm pretty sure they are messed up during deployment. WebDeploy has a tendency to do strange things with connection strings, you need to stop it. So when you deploy, on settings page **uncheck** "Use this connection string":

[image: Web-deploy connection strings]

And once you have deployed to Azure you can check the state of `web.config` either through Visual Studio 2013 Server Explorer:

[image: VS2013 Server Explorer Web.config]

Or through Kudu which you can access via `https://<mywebsitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `web.config`:

[image: Kudu diagnostic panel]

Comment: Cool, interesting. Am using web-sites atm. Sadly the connection string in there is exactly the same as the one above. So hasn't helped i'm afraid.

Comment: Then go into deployed files and check what are the values for connection strings in `web.config`.

Comment: are these the connection strings from the web-site? or these are part of web-deployment package?

Comment: updated the question again (they are from the web.config in the package folder in the web project that i am publishing)

Comment: do you check the boxes on deployment for "Use connection string"? (This: http://goo.gl/IssrVg) Uncheck these boxes, re-deploy. Go through ftp (or VS2013 server explorer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24572549/809357) to the actual site in azure and check your connection strings on the site. I bet you, your connection strings are messed up during deployment!

Comment: hey can you add your comment as an answer ... also your image link has expired. (for reference it was the use and update connection string for defaultConnection - rather than the entity context connection string)

Comment: @JohnNicholas updated my answer and restored screenshot image

Comment: sadly cant upvote your answer again ;p sorry for taking ages to test, went off working on another area.